# KeyError when using mutate method in FeedItemService

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I have an ad customizer feed setup in my account and I want to change the value of one Item in that feed. I tried doing that using the "SET" operation in the 'FeedItemService'

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
KeyError: 'feedAttributes'
```

I have gone through the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201809/FeedItemService.FeedItemAttributeValue

I also went through the 'ADD' new feedItem code example here:
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/ad-customizers

However, that's only to ADD new items rather than modify (SET) them.

Here is the code snippet:

```
fi_service = adwords_client.GetService('FeedItemService', version = 'v201809')

fi_operator = {                 
                'feedId': 1234,
                'feedItemId': 3456,                
                'attributeValues': [
                                    {                                     
                                     'feedAttributeId':111,
                                     'stringValue': '1000'}

                                    ]
        }
fi_creator_operation = {'operator': 'SET',                        
                        'operand': fi_operator}                

fi_call_response = fi_service.mutate(feed_creator_operation)
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-57-892b092f7b88>", line 15, in <module>
    fi_call_response = fi_service.mutate(feed_creator_operation)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\googleads\common.py", line 1381, in MakeSoapRequest
    packed_args = self._PackArguments(method_name, args)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\googleads\common.py", line 1239, in _PackArguments
    for ((_, param), param_data) in izip(op_params, args)]

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\googleads\common.py", line 1284, in _PackArgumentsHelper
    elem_type, type_override is not None, data_formatted, set_type_attrs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\googleads\common.py", line 1351, in _CreateComplexTypeFromData
    for k, v in data if k != 'xsi_type'}

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\googleads\common.py", line 1351, in <dictcomp>
    for k, v in data if k != 'xsi_type'}

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\googleads\common.py", line 1284, in _PackArgumentsHelper
    elem_type, type_override is not None, data_formatted, set_type_attrs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\googleads\common.py", line 1351, in _CreateComplexTypeFromData
    for k, v in data if k != 'xsi_type'}

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\googleads\common.py", line 1351, in <dictcomp>
    for k, v in data if k != 'xsi_type'}

KeyError: 'feedAttributes'
```

I have tried experimenting with adding ('xsi_type': 'feedAttributes') in the various dictionaries (fi_operator, attributeValues, fi_creator_operation), just in case it worked, however, I still get the same response.